# edited: symfony plus complex database connectivity

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine, pdo

So, I must say that I am completely new to symfony, i've been using it for a total of about 4 days now but I've come quite far in my knowledge thus far...

I was recently put onto a project to add a new feature, so I checked out the repo via git and created the new entity and the crud to begin working on it...  It's worth noting that this system is using the PDO MySQL drivers.

In my doctrine config yml for my entity I have:

```
Ecs\CrmBundle\Entity\TimeClock:
type: entity
table: null
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    in1:
        type: datetime
    out1:
        type: datetime
    in2:
        type: datetime
    out2:
        type: datetime
    totaltime:
        type: string
    daydate:
        type: datetime
manyToOne:
    noteBy:
        targetEntity:  Ecs\AgentManagerBundle\Entity\User
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

This is for a timeclock for our employees to use...  Then in my timeclock controller, in the `index()` function what I need to do is search the database for entries that are this payperiod but only for the agent that is logged in...

So lets say for example that i've already written the code for `$start` and `$end` that will hold dates in the datetime format...  so like:

`$start = "2012-03-24 00:00:00"` and `$end = "2012-03-31 23:59:59"` respectively..

The code I currently have that is pulling all entries for the agent logged in is:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    // date format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
    $entities = $em->getRepository('EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock')->findBy(array('noteBy' => $user->getid()));

    return $this->render('EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
}
```

So, how do I expand upon `$entities` to include narrowing it down with `$start` and `$end`?

[EDIT]

I've done a little research and ive re-written the `indexAction` function a little bit..

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    // date format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
    $today = time();
    if (date('l') == "Saturday") {
        $end = date('Y-m-d ')."23:59:59";
    } else {
        $end = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('next_saturday', $today))."23:59:59";
    }
    $start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('last_sunday', $today));
    $entities = $em->getRepository('EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock');
    echo $user->getid();
    $query = $entities->createQueryBuilder('tc')
        ->where('tc.noteBy = :user')
        ->where('tc.daydate <= :end')
        ->where('tc.daydate >= :start')
        ->setParameter('user', $user->getid())
        ->setParameter('end', $end)
        ->setParameter('start', $start)
        ->getQuery();
    $entities = $query->getResult();

    return $this->render('EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
}
```

But now when I run it, it gives me this:

`Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens` but doesn't tell me where the problem is...  If i remove the 2 `where(tc.daydate)` and the corresponding `setParameter` functions, it returns the expected results minus the filtering on the date they were entered..  any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after searching and searching and coming up with not much of anything...  The problem, as i'm guessing was too many `where` commands...

```
 public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    // date format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
    $today = time();
    if (date('l') == "Saturday") {
        $end = date('Y-m-d ')."23:59:59";
    } else {
        $end = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('next_saturday', $today))."23:59:59";
    }
    $start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('last_sunday', $today));
    $entities = $em->getRepository('EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock');
    echo $user->getid();
    $query = $entities->createQueryBuilder('tc')
        ->where('tc.noteBy = :user')
        ->andWhere('tc.daydate <= :end')
        ->andWhere('tc.daydate >= :start')
        ->setParameter('user', $user->getid())
        ->setParameter('end', $end)
        ->setParameter('start', $start)
        ->getQuery();
    $entities = $query->getResult();

    return $this->render('EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
}
```

changing the 2 for the `daydate` to `andWhere` fixed the problem completely..